# How can I convert this object into an Array using GAS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got this showing as an `object`:
`38,44,46`
...while and it should be:
["38","44","46"]

I'd like to convert it to an Array, so that I can iterate over it.
I've tried doing so using this, but it's still an object, as I get its type:
`let tamanhosEsc = Object.values(values[29]);`

This is how `values` is created:

```
const rngList = cadSheet.getRangeList(dataRng).getRanges();

  let values = new Array();

  for(let i = 0; i < rngList.length; i++) {
    let data = rngList[i].getValue();
    values.push([data]);
  }
```

I've tried creating it by specifying it as an Array, but still...

Comment: Its unclear what dataRng is but is should be an Array of ranges in R1C1 notation.  ["A1:B3", C2:D5","F10:K99"] for example.  Or if as you have shown its a sincle cell then ["A1","B2","C3"].  So for example .getRangeList(["A1","B2","C3"]) would return an Array of ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play with the code above to understand the basic concept:

```
var obj = {"1":5,"2":7,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0}
var result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [Number(key), obj[key]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi! Even when the object doesn't seem to have keys, but only values?